# migrating static assets served by nginx to netlify

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, netlify

i love using netifly for my static assets. i have a legacy vuejs app that i used to generate static assets.  the static assets are served through nginx that is correctly running on cloud run in a docker container.  i attempted to move it to netlify, but found out some errors from what looks like some relative url reference in the code.  i also tried this on s3 buckets and had the same issue.  my guess is having to use a cname vs a static ipaddress.  anybody run into issues like this? i'll give it another go soon.

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue.  it has to do with putting the file _redirects with this content in the main root directory.

/* /index.html 200

this is the netlify reference:

https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/01/16/redirect-rules-for-all-how-to-configure-redirects-for-your-static-site/